# Did Captain Lorca arrange the prison transport incident in Context is for Kings?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery, captain-lorca

In [Star Trek Discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Discovery) [S1:E3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_Is_for_Kings) - *Context is for Kings*, we see a prison transport [accident](https://www.vox.com/2017/10/1/16387154/star-trek-discovery-s1-ep-3-recap).

Later there is a discussion between [Burnham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Burnham) and Captain [Lorca](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Gabriel_Lorca). In it Captain Lorca suggests he has [read](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/tv/reviews/star-trek-discovery-season-1-episode-3-context-is-for-kings-review-s01e03-captain-lorca-tribble-a7979021.html) her file, and that Burnam has the kind of attributes he is looking for.

It's not clear if he read the file prior to the prison transport accident, or after he got them onto the ship.

My question is: **Did Captain Lorca arrange the prison transport incident in Context is for Kings?**

**EDIT**
I believe this is not a duplicate because the subject of the other question isn't clear - nor is the question - it is merely an open-ended invitation to comment on the plot.

Comment: While your question is better written, it seems that the answers on the dupe target will also answer this question.

Comment: My point is that if you were looking for an answer to this question you wouldn’t find those answers. It fails the discoverability test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is heavily suggested by dialogue, ("You're right. I did choose you."), not to mention the sheer improbability of the coincidence, that Lorca did arrange the entire prison transport incident. If Burnham had turned out to be intractable, he could always have put her back on the shuttle with the rest of the convicts and sent her off to rot in a dilithium mine.

Because of the style the story is being told (third-person limited, mostly focused on Burnham), however, we're unlikely to ever see an unambiguous moment where Lorca pulled the strings to arrange things.